# jQuery Regex wrong match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a text in a textarea like this;

```
[Some Text][2][2]:SomeText
```

I want to change first 2 to 1. To do this I try to match `[Some Text][1]` by following regex

```
regex = new RegExp("(\\[.*\\]\\[)2(\\])");
```

and replace it by using this code;

```
textarea.val().replace(regex, "$11$2");
```

However my regex match `[Some Text][2][2]` and replace second 2 with 1. How can i match `[Some Text][2]` and replace first 2.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7bjovnc/)

Comment: Just use `regex = /(\[.*\]\[)2(\])/;`

Comment: As for the actual problem, use lazy matching: `"(\\[.*?\\]` (notice the `?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.*` is too greedy, change your regex to this:

```
regex = new RegExp("(\\[[^\\]]*\\]\\[)2(\\])");
```

You can also use:

```
regex = new RegExp("(\\[.*?\\]\\[)2(\\])");
```

#### [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f7bjovnc/1/)

Comment: what is the meaning of .*? 
is that means every character but optional?

Comment: `?` in `.*?` is called lazy quantifier.

Comment: is it a special condition?

Comment: NO nothing special about it. `?` after `*` or `+` makes it a lazy match.